# Malloc in function in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

Hi I'm trying to neaten up my code by moving all of my Malloc calls (ans subsequent malloc checks) into one routine which looks like:

```
int Malloc2D(int n, int m, double** array_ptr) {

array_ptr = (double**) malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
if (array_ptr == NULL) {
    std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array_ptr[i] = (double*) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    if (array_ptr[i] == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

But when in main() I do something like:

```
double** test;
if(Malloc2d(10, 20, test) == -1) return -1;
```

and then try and use the array in main I get a segfault? Anyone got any ideas?
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++ are pass-by-value.
So changes made to `array_ptr` inside your function `Malloc2D` are not visible outside the function.

You want to pass a pointer to test, and modify the value of that.
*(which leads to a triple-pointer; confusing, but not unmanageable)*

```
int Malloc2D(int n, int m, double*** pOutput)
{
    double** array_ptr
    array_ptr = (double**) malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
    if (array_ptr == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array_ptr[i] = (double*) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
        if (array_ptr[i] == NULL) {
            std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    *pOutput = array_ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Then to use the function, pass the address of `test`:

```
double** test;
if(Malloc2d(10, 20, &test) == -1) return -1;
```

Comment: So if I were to have Malloc2D only take the two dimensions of the array and pass back a pointer to the start that would be ok?

Comment: You can pass references in C++

Comment: True, we could go to a reference.   I chose not to.

Comment: If I may ask, is there any particular reason not to chose reference?

Comment: The OP didn't bring up references.  He's trying to do everything with pointers.  And I'm an old-school C programmer, references aren't always my first thought (though I should use them more often)

Comment: Fair enough! It very much seems that OP is leaning toward `C` style coding (using `malloc` instead of `new`, not using `vector` etc) for good reasons known to him although the code is in `C++`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing a `double **array_ptr` it won't modify the pointer outside the function.

In C++, you could fix it by making it a reference (and use `new`, since it's C++)

```
int Malloc2D(int n, int m, double**& array_ptr) {

array_ptr = new double*[n]);
if (array_ptr == NULL) {
    std::cout << "ERROR! new failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array_ptr[i] = new double[m];
    if (array_ptr[i] == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR! new failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Or, in C-style fashion, we could use another pointer indirection (using `&test` in the calling code to pass the address of the `double ** test`).

```
int Malloc2D(int n, int m, double*** array_ptr) {

*array_ptr = (double**) malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
if (array_ptr == NULL) {
    std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    (*array_ptr)[i] = (double*) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    if ((*array_ptr)[i] == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Or you could simply return the pointer to the array in the first place - but this would require some minor changes to the calling code:

```
double** Malloc2D(int n, int m) {

double** array_ptr;
array_ptr = (double**) malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
if (array_ptr == NULL) {
    std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array_ptr[i] = (double*) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    if (array_ptr[i] == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR! malloc failed on line " << __LINE__ << "..." << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}

return array_ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a pointer or a reference on your `double array_ptr`. Here, it is copied, and only the copy is modified.

```
int Malloc2D(int n, int m, double** &array_ptr)
```

Answer (score 1):

> and then try and use the array in main I get a segfault

The problem is that you are not modifying `array_ptr` since it is being passed by value. One possible solution would be to pass it by reference:

```
int Malloc2D(int n, int m, double** &array_ptr)
                                    ^
```